# Multiple Eaccelerator Issues

Tags: php, centos, apc, prestashop, eaccelerator

### General info

Linux Centos GoDaddy VPS with Prestashop Ecommerce site

### Issues created by Eaccelerator

**1)** Since installing eaccelerator, the php related wait time has risen 500 ms and I have no idea why.

Before Eaccelerator Installation: http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/zdViZURr3/http://www.kikbo.com/buy
After Eaccelerator Installation:
http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/NrPauzEMD/http://www.kikbo.com/buy

**2)** When using the following php.ini configuration, I get a 500 internal server error whenever I go to any of the dynamically generated pages on my website.

```
[eacclerator]
extension="eaccelerator.so"
eaccelerator.shm_size="16"
eaccelerator.cache_dir="/tmp/eaccelerator"
eaccelerator.enable="1"
eaccelerator.optimizer="1"
eaccelerator.check_mtime="1"
eaccelerator.debug="1" [set as 1 to check the errors]
eaccelerator.filter=""
eaccelerator.shm_max="0"
eaccelerator.shm_ttl="0"
eaccelerator.shm_prune_period="0"
eaccelerator.shm_only="0"
eaccelerator.compress="1"
eaccelerator.compress_level="9"
```

When I check the error_log, it tells me eaccelerator is caching but gives me no further indication as to why its causing a 500 internal server error.

```
EACCELERATOR cached: "...index.php"
```

**3)** When I change this:

```
extension="eaccelerator.so"
```

to this:

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib64/php/modules/eaccelerator.so"
```

I cease to receive the 500 internal server error and eaccelerator shows up in phpinfo(). After someone visits the site, scripts get cached, but they don't stay that way. They disappear quickly and "scripts cached" becomes 1, and "scripts removed" becomes 0.

[image: eaccelerator problems]
<sub>(source: [kikbo.com](http://www.kikbo.com/stackoverflow/eaccelerator.JPG))</sub>

Further, when I command line: php -v I don't see anything about eaccelerator. And even further, I see no benefit in php computing time.

When I check the error log I now see eaccelerator caching and getting "hit":

```
EACCELERATOR hit: "...index.php"
EACCELERATOR cached: "...config.inc.php"
```

### My questions

Is there some way I can "undo" this eaccelerator installation? It slowed down my website and I can't sort out why. It seems like I should be using APC...but in any case can these problems be corrected and if so what is causing them?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to uninstall it or will just disabling it do what you need? If you set the enable key to 0 then eaccelerator won't be used.

Comment: I tried both to no avail. I ended up reprovisioning the server and reinstalling everything but eaccelerator and my wait times are way down.

Sorta looks like no one uses eaccelerator anyways.